# What do the different columns in the "!heap -flt -s xxxx" windbg command represent

Tags: debugging, heap-memory, windbg

I've been doing some work on high memory issues, and I've been doing a lot of heap analysis in windbg, and I was curious what the different columns really mean in "!heap -flt -s xxxx" command.

I read [What do the 'size' numbers mean in the windbg !heap output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706634/what-do-the-size-numbers-mean-in-the-windbg-heap-output), and I looked in my "Windows Internals" book, but I still had a bunch of questions. So the columns and my questions are below.

```
**HEAP_ENTRY** - What does this pointer really point to? How is it different than UserPtr?
**Size** - What does this size mean? How is it different than UserSize?
**Prev** - This just appears to be the negative offset to get to the previous heap entry. Still not sure exactly how it's used.
**Flags** - Is there any documentation on these flags?
**UserPtr** - What is the user pointer? In all cases I've seen it's always 8 bytes higher than the HEAP_ENTRY, but I don't really know what it points to.
**UserSize** - This appears to be the size of the actual allocation.
**state** - This just tells you what state of this heap entry is (free, busy, etc....)

Example:
HEAP_ENTRY Size Prev Flags    UserPtr UserSize - state
  0015eeb0 0044 0000  [07]   0015eeb8    00204 - (busy)
```

Comment: nice question.. I've wondered the same thing

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**HEAP_ENTRY**
Heaps store allocated blocks in contiguous Segments of memory, each allocated block starts with a 8-bytes header followed by the actual allocated data. The HEAP_ENTRY column is the address of the beginning of the header of the allocated block.

**Size**
The heap manager handles blocks in multiple of 8 bytes. The column is the number of 8 bytes chunk allocated. In your sample, 0044 means that the block takes 0x220 bytes (0x44*8).

**Prev**
Multiply per 8 to have the negative offset in bytes to the previous heap block.

**Flags**
This is a bitmask that encodes the following information

```
0x01 - HEAP_ENTRY_BUSY
0x02 - HEAP_ENTRY_EXTRA_PRESENT
0x04 - HEAP_ENTRY_FILL_PATTERN
0x08 - HEAP_ENTRY_VIRTUAL_ALLOC
0x10 - HEAP_ENTRY_LAST_ENTRY
```

**UserPtr**
This is the pointer returned to the application by the HeapAlloc (callbed by malloc/new) function. Since the header is always 8 bytes long, it is always HEAP_ENTRY +8.

**UserSize**
This is the size passed the HeapAlloc function.

**state**
This is a decoding of the Flags column, telling if the entry is busy, freed, last of its segment, …

Be aware that in Windows 7/2008 R2, heaps are by default using a front-end named LFH (Low fragmented heap) that uses the default heap manager to allocate chunks in which it dispatched user allocated data. For these heaps, UserPtr and UserSize will not point to real user data.
The output of `!heap -s` displays which heaps are LFH enabled.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to get the real userptr in LFH heaps (that's what was originally driving this question)?

Comment: !heap -p knows about LFH but has less options. You can get the real userptr from an address with !heap -p -a <address>. !heap -p -all will list all user blocks for all heaps. If you redirect the output in a file, you may then grep for blocks of wanted user size.

Comment: The thread is quite old, but be aware that for x64, the user ptr location is HEAP_ENTRY +16 because `sizeof(_HEAP_ENTRY)` from ntdll.dll returns 0x10 / 16 bytes. Also newer versions of WinDBG appear to be correctly mapping UserPtr to data, although I don't know yet how or why they weren't doing it in older versions

Answer (score 4):

From looking at the !heap documentation in the Debugging Tools for Windows help file and the heap docs on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366798%28VS.85%29.aspx) and a great [excerpt](http://www.prototypical.co.uk/pdf/awd.pdf) from [Advanced Windows Debugging](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321374460), here's what I've been able to put together:

- **HEAP_ENTRY**: pointer to entry within the heap. As you found, there is an 8 byte header which contains the data for the HEAP_ENTRY structure. The size of the HEAP_ENTRY structure is 8 bytes which defines the "heap granularity" size. This is used for determining the...
- **SIZE**: size of the entry in terms of the granularity (i.e. the allocation size / 8)
- **FLAGS**: these are defined in winbase.h with explanations found the in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366798%28VS.85%29.aspx) link.
- **USERPTR**: the actual pointer to the allocated (or freed) object

Answer (score 1):

Well, the main difference between HEAP_ENTRY and UserPtr is the due to the fact that heaps have to be indexed, allocated, filled with metadata (like the allocated length made available to user)... otherwise, how could you free(p) something without providing how many bytes were allocated? Same thing with the two size fields: one thing is how big the structure indexing the heap is, one thing is how big is the memory region made available to the user.

The FLAGS, in turn, basically specify which properties of the allocated memory block, if it is committed or just reserved, and, I guess, used by the kernel to rearrange or share memory regions if needed (but as nithins specifies they are documented in MSDN).

The PREV ptr is used to keep track of all the allocated regions and the first pointer is stored in the PEB structure so both user-space and kernel-space code is aware of the allocated heap pools.